# What does the save button in the editor do?

Tags: excel, vba

I could not find a simple answer to this question, which I thought was odd. I was making changes to an Add-in I wrote and I was pressing the save button ever so often in the excel VBA editor. When I came back to make some more changes I found that all my changes over the last few days are gone. Is there any hope of recovering my work? More importantly, if I am making changes what is a better way of saving the project. I usually work out of my add on and only save a new copy when I need to send it out to a teammate.

Comment: The Save button in the VBE is extremely unreliable. I suggest you just add a routine to your add-in with a line like `ThisWorkbook.Save` and run that whenever you want to save (that's what I do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember having this bad surprise at some point, but then I started to look closely at the save button before clicking and I noticed that VBA is telling you which workbook will be saved if you click on the floppy disk.

[image]

The reason why it is important to have a look at this is because the file that will be saved depends on what is currently selected in the **Project Explorer** and not what is currently visible in the **VBA Code Editor Window**.

[image]

You can also make sure that your add-in is properly saved by selecting one of its elements and running the following command in the **Immediate Window** (which should replicate exactly what the VBE save button does):

```
Thisworkbook.Save
```

Finally, unlike for other types of workbooks, Excel won't tell you when you close the application without saving changes to an add-in. For that reason, you can take extra precautions by adding the following code to the object `Thisworkbook` of your add-in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
        Dim strMsg As String

        ' Specify the message to display.
        strMsg = "Want to save your changes to '" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'?"

        Dim Decision As Boolean, ireply As Variant
        ireply = MsgBox(prompt:=strMsg, Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel)
        If ireply = vbYes Then
            Decision = True
        ElseIf ireply = vbNo Then
            Decision = False
        Else 'They cancelled (VbCancel)
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Decision = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Save
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Which will prompt you with a message allowing you to save your add-in if it has an *unsaved* status when the Excel application is closing.

Comment: I appreciate the great write up and I will start using the code you provided as a safe guard. Was my mistake working out of a blank workbook? When I hover over the floppy I see 'Save '[Add-In File Name] (Ctrl+S)'. 

I am guessing that anytime I want to make a change I should do a save as in excel to create a new excel Add-In file and work from that?

Comment: Well, if you were working out of a new blank workbook and after clicking on the VBE floppy you don't see the usual SaveAs dialog, there is something wrong. After a file has already been saved once, the floppy *should* work as a simple save button for the active VBProject.

Comment: I think I figured out my mistake. I thought that any saves were going to file that was contained in the Add-Ins folder and not to the original file. Once When I pulled the Add-Ins file out I had to overwrite my original file, thus loosing my work. I loaded a previous version of the Add-In all my saves started actually saving. The file I loaded shows an updated modified date as well. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, even if it was user error!